# Is there a way to distribute my Android app as a windows (and Mac) app

Tags: android, windows, macos, native

Is there a way to develop an Android app, and then wrap and distribute it as a single-download native Windows and/or Mac app?
Perhaps first wrapping it as a Java app, and then wrapping that again as a native app?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you expect the end user to run the android emulator to run them.

Comment: So then the question is if I can bundle the emulator on Windows and Mac invisibly to the end user ...